# Error with installing 'prefixscan' package using pip

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, package, failed-installation, python-packaging

I'm having trouble installing 'prefixscan' package for my machine learning project even though the requirements are satisfied. The following are printed in CMD:

```
Collecting prefixspan
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/b0/e66e9f6e07a0b37aa0f5703c46f54bafbdf65dfba63994247676b19076c4/prefixspan-0.5.2.tar.gz
Collecting docopt>=0.6.2 (from prefixspan)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/55/8f8cab2afd404cf578136ef2cc5dfb50baa1761b68c9da1fb1e4eed343c9/docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz
Collecting extratools>=0.8.1 (from prefixspan)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/76/e0184ff4581ee592a24e888cce3d7f08c09326fb074172e9085b0bca787d/extratools-0.8.1.tar.gz
Collecting RegexOrder>=0.2 (from extratools>=0.8.1->prefixspan)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/2e/ba45fe736713c4673e59ddb9f27f0f72cf83ff0bf2108b8f4b8df93df3d2/RegexOrder-0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vsf7xk06\RegexOrder\setup.py", line 17
        download_url=f"{url}/tarball/{version}",
                                              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vsf7xk06\RegexOrder\
```

The python version is 3.7.0 > 3.6 required. 
Assistance in overcoming this installation issue is highly valued.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a conflicting path variable with the older version of python which was Python v3.5.